Why do (some) LaTeX fonts have separate 8pt and 10pt font files?
I was just looking at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf, and I noticed something that's puzzled me for a while, but never got around to asking: usually, when I install a usual Windows font, like Arial, there are separate font files for e.g. regular and bold, but then since the font (as I understand it) is a vector description, it can be "resized" at any font size the application desires.
And yet, in New Computer Modern (and other font's I've), there are these files:

https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf/NewCM08-Regular.otf
https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf/NewCM10-Regular.otf

Why have two separate font files, for the same font style and family, for 8 pt and 10 pt? Are they not scalable? Or have I misunderstood the meaning of 8 and 10 in the filenames?

Scalable is not always the same as looking good at small sizes.

Thanks @daleif - so basically, there is actually a slightly different font in each file, so that some features would be more visible at small sizes, is that it?

You can probably see it with some commercial fonts, where there are sepcific designs for small sizes. But making them takes a lot of work, så not sure how common it is.

Not every font comes with different designs for different sizes, but some do. Modern variable fonts can select a different design for a different font size as well. Typically, fonts for smaller sizes are designed a bit thicker and wider while for larger font sizes, the glyphs become thinner and also more detailed (for example the serifs).

@sdbbs Yes, you've understood it correctly. See this https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/choosing_type/choosing_typefaces_that_have_optical_sizes

But then what about the math fonts? There's no math fonts specified for a specific size

@ApoorvPotnis - It depends: Some math fonts -- notably, the Computer Modern and Latin Modern math fonts, and a few others as well (for instance, the MathTime Professional fonts) -- indeed provide optically sized variants for \scriptstyle (for a 30% linear reduction in font size, suitable for level-1 subscript and superscript material) and for \scriptscriptstyle (for a 50% linear reduction in font size, suitable for level-2 subscript and superscript material) settings.

Also possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356906/do-font-files-e-g-ttc-ttf-otf-contain-different-weights

@ApoorvPotnis I am not sure what you mean by "There's no math fonts specified for a specific size" ? For classic tex, math fonts are probably the main reason for having optical scaling, so that subscripts stay legible even though they are small.

@DavidCarlisle I mean that the NewCMMath-Book.otf file does not have any number. So if I consider the letter A in this font, is it meant to be used with NewCM08-Book.otf or NewCM10-Book.otf? That was my question.

@Mico continued from the previous comment. I think NewCMMath-Book.otf is meant to be used with NewCM10-Book.otf from visual inspection. In that case, what letters from the math font should used with NewCM08-Book.otf?

There is only one math font so you need to scale it to all available sizes, I think you could still use the 10 and 8 design size fonts there is no right and wrong here but you can look at the latex package newcomputermodern to see what the font developer thought were reasonable choices (which use 8 and 10  in text and just the math font in math, as far as I can see)

The smaller the font, the more difficult it is to let all the diacritical accents look different that appear in texts of most European languages (and as wiggles and arrows and sub/superscripts in mathematics). So a redesign makes sense if scaling from 10 to 8pts.

Some fonts, notably the classic Computer Modern fonts that were designed for use with TeX, use "optical scaling" where fonts designed for specific sizes are constructed rather than simply automatically scaling a base font.
This allows any changes that are desired by the font designer, but typically fonts designed for small sizes are wider for the same nominal height, so that they remain legible, and fonts designed for large sizes may have thinner strokes to allow large headline text without looking so bold.
It is often easiest to compare by scaling the small font up to a larger size.
Here, is a plain tex document showing cmr5 at its natural 5pt size, and scaled to 12pt, compared with cmr12 at its natural 12pt size and scaled to 5pt.



\font\fa=cmr5
\font\fb=cmr12 at 5pt
\font\fc=cmr5 at 12pt
\font\fd=cmr12

\parskip=10pt

{\fa One two three four five}

{\fb One two three four five}

{\fc One two three four five}

{\fd One two three four five}

\bye

You will note that as well as being wider and with thicker strokes, the cmr5 font drops the fi ligature, and has a rounder O.

Classic TeX uses lots of small (127 character) fonts so the designer could choose in each case whether to provide designed optical variants or to allow the font to be scaled. cmr, for the characters most used in superscripts, has fonts at each of cmr[5,6,7,8,9,10,12,17].
For large OpenType fonts with thousands of characters, having so many variants when the majority of the characters are indistinguishable from the
automatically scaled variant is probably not feasible. The NCM author appears to have decided that 8pt and 10pt design fonts are a useful tradeoff, presumably NCM8 can be scaled down for sub and subsub scripts or used in other "small print" contexts, and NCM10 can be scaled up for all larger type size use.
